# Jquery accessing distanced parents

Tags: jquery, html, dom, click, parent

Consider the following HTML structure for drop-down menu:

```
<ul class="tabMenu">
    <li><a href="#">Games</a>
     <div id="sub">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Main</a></li>                         
          <li><a href="#">3D</a></li>
       </ul>
     </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Videos</a>
         <div id="sub">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Main</a></li>                         
              <li><a href="#">3D</a></li>
           </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Under this menu I write some string using Jquery(Home is the default value) which tells the user where he is:

```
<div class="Pointer"><a href="#">Home</a></div>
```

The following Jquery is used for detecting which category/subcategory is trigerred:

```
$('.tabMenu li a').click(function() {
            //get current link
            var currentLink = $(this);
            //get link text
            var linkText = currentLink.text();
            //Remove all activeTab classes
            $('.activeTab').removeClass('activeTab');
            //Add selected class with activeTab
            currentLink.parent().addClass("activeTab");
                    //Change pointer value according to the click
            $('.Pointer a').html(linkText);
        });
```

The Jquery function should return string which looks like Videos->Main if the user clicks subcategory 'Main' from the drop-down on 'Videos' and Games->Main if the user chooses Main from Games. This code gives only Main no matter if it was clicked from 'Games' or 'Videos' Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery `closest` which get the first ancestor element that matches the selector, beginning at the current element and progressing up through the DOM tree.

Working **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sY7fe/2/)**

```
$('.tabMenu li a').click(function() {
            //get current link
            var currentLink = $(this);
            //get link text
            var linkText = currentLink.text();

            //Remove all activeTab classes
            $('.activeTab').removeClass('activeTab');
            //Add selected class with activeTab
            currentLink.parent().addClass("activeTab");
                    //Change pointer value according to the click
            linkText = currentLink.closest('div').closest("li").children("a").text() + " > " + linkText ;
            $('.Pointer a').html(linkText);
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
// Will only affect subcategory links
$('.tabMenu li #sub a').click(function() {
  var parentCategory = $(this).parent().parents('li:first').children('a:first').html()
})
// Will only affect "Games" and "Videos" links
$('.tabMenu > li > a').click(function() {
  var category = $(this).html() 
})
```

Of course you could use them both in the selector `".tabMenu li #sub a"` but I think this way is cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

In first place, you can only have one instance of the same id. (id="sub"). Change that to a class.

Try stopping event bubbling, in other words, make sure the script is only executed once per click.